# Is information about game assets copyrighted?

Tags: assets, copyright

Let's say I extracted some assets from a closed source game.

Am I allowed to publish information (something like a list of filenames, sizes, duration, dimensions...) about those assets?

Comment: Judging by some youtubers, that publish information about "hidden assets" in games, I'd say there shouldn't be any copyright problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facts are not protected by copyrights but you should check if there aren't other local laws that apply where you live.

From [USA law, www.copyright.gov, Library of Congress](https://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-protect.html)

> Copyright does not protect facts, ideas, systems, or methods of
>   operation, although it may protect the way these things are expressed.

Many countries have [international treaties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright#International_copyright_treaties) to follow the same general copyright law (See [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention)). But not all follow the USA's copyright [term extension act (A.K.A. Mickey Mouse Protection Act)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_Term_Extension_Act) that were changed after the initial agreement and every country will have variation in their interpretation of what constitute fair use.

Comment: Some term of service & end-user license agreements may prohibit such disclosures (whether or not they have an legal merit, may be another matter). If the info published can be used to circumvent measures that control access to copyrighted works, in the US it is likely subject to the Digital Millennium Copyright Act.

Comment: also note that this is US law; law in other countries may be different.